# Write Parcelable object got java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, java-io, parcelable

I have a class named **Shop**, which has **2 fields and 1 static field**. The class implements **Parcelable** interface:

```
public class Shop implements Parcelable{
   private static int SHOP_ID = 12;

   private String name;
   private long fund;

   //constructor with parcel
   public Shop(Parcel parcel){
       name = parcel.readString();
       fund = parcel.readLong();
   }

   //normal constructor
   public Shop(Owner owner){
        name = owner.getShopName();
        fund = owner.getFund();
    }

    @Override
  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
      dest.writeString(name);
      dest.writeLong(fund);
    }

    public static final Creator<Shop> CREATOR = new Creator<Shop>(){

       @Override
       public Shop createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        //use the constructor which accept parcel
        return new Shop(parcel);
       }

       @Override
       public Shop[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Shop[size];
       }

    };
}
```

Now, my code initiate a **Shop** instance by using the normal constructor:

```
Owner owner = getOwnerInfo();
Shop myShop = new Shop(owner); //initiate a Shop with owner
```

Then , my code store the `shop` instance to internal storage of Android:

```
String fileName = "shop_file";
try{
  FileOutputStream fos = activity.openFileOutput(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);         

  oos.writeObject(myShop); 
  oos.flush();
  oos.close();
}catch(Exception ex){
  ...
}
```

But when run my app, I got **java.io.NotSerializableException** :

```
06-12 13:04:29.258: W/System.err(2632): java.io.NotSerializableException: com.my.app.model.Shop
06-12 13:04:29.258: W/System.err(2632):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
06-12 13:04:29.266: W/System.err(2632):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
06-12 13:04:29.266: W/System.err(2632):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
```

Why? where am I wrong?

Comment: You try to use Java's own serialization mechanism (using Serializable interface) which is different from Android's parcel-mechanism.

Comment: I don't understand you, I am using Parcelable, why you said I am not?? For what I understood, Parcelable is an Android version Serializable interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the execption seems you are trying to serialize an instance of CartData that does not implements `Serializable`:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.my.app.model.Shop
```

If you want to serialize it you should let `Shop implemensts Serializable`

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class
>   (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects
>   into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As
>   such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent
>   storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data
>   in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Comment: Hi, That is my typo. I have updated my post, please check again

Comment: still my answer does not change. You have to let shop implements both Serializable and Parcelable if you want to get both

Comment: Isn't Parcelable a Android specific Serializable interface ? Why I need to implements both ??

Comment: still to use write object with ObjectOutputStream you have to implements Serializable

Comment: Ok, so, you mean Parcelable object is not supported by ObjectOutputStream as a special version of serializable. By the way, could you please update the Exception text in your post, it is different than my post, which may confuse other visitors.

Comment: Thanks blackbelt, by the way, if in my Shop class, I have another field which is a reference to another Object, e.g. Car car, should the Car class also implements serializable in order to use persistent storage on my shop instance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31644/discussion-between-mellon-and-blackbelt)

Comment: yes, all the fields are to be serializable. You can mark a field as transient if you want not to serialize it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from your "Owner" object which is not serialized too. try to serialize this object with the Parcelable